# Why is my POST request not redirecting as expected in my unit test even though there are no form errors?

Tags: django, redirect, django-forms, http-post, django-unittest

I've got a Django view with a form, which I'm POSTing to in a unit test. Here's the general structure of the test:

```
class ViewTests(TestCase):
    form_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:form')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('myapp:success')

    def test_form_submission_with_valid_data_creates_new_object_and_redirects(self):
        attributes = EntryFactory.attributes()
        attributes['product'] = ProductFactory()  # Entry has a ForeignKey to Product
        response = self.client.post(self.form_url, attributes, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertRedirects(response, self.success_url)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'myapp/success.html')
```

However, I can't seem to figure out why the redirect isn't working as expected. I've tried dropping in a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to see if there are any form errors (`response.context['form'].errors`), but all I get back is an empty dict. Submitting the form in the browser redirects properly, so I'm not sure why the unit test is failing, and also not sure how to debug it properly since no errors are showing up in the form error dict.

Comment: That is a horribly long name for a function

Comment: oh and regards to your question, since the test fails on the redirection I hardly believe it has anything to do with your form. Can you share your urls.py and also the exact failure message you are seeing? I'm suspecting a bad link is probably the source of the problem

Comment: @yuvi It sure is, but this 'horribly long name' will come in handy when there are a whole lot of unit tests and you'd like to know what a failed one does from its name.

Comment: seems like 'valid_form_and_redirect' would be just hunky-dory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take that under consideration. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were a few things wrong.

First, there was actually a second form on the page (for selection of `Product`) that I missed. Relatedly, I should have assigned `ProductFactory().id` to `attributes['product']`, rather than `ProductFactory`.

Second, after I changed that bit, there was an issue with the `assertRedirects`; I had to change `self.success_url` to `unicode(self.success_url)` since `assertRedirects` can't perform a comparison with a proxy.

Final product:

```
def test_form_submission_with_valid_data_create_new_entry_and_redirects(self):
    attributes = EntryFactory.attributes()
    attributes['product'] = ProductFactory().id
    response = self.client.post(self.form_url, attributes)
    self.assertRedirects(response, unicode(self.success_url))
```